# In Python how do you make the variable in an f'-string a range of numbers which are inserted and run one by one

Tags: python, selenium, f-string

I'm pretty new to the coding world, so maybe someone can help me. Might even be a straight forward problem.
Currently I'm using selenium and python for a project, but I can't find anything helpful so far.
Would it be possible to define the variables in a f-string as a range of numbers which are inserted in the placeholder one by one so selenium can check each f string seperately? Thats what I got so far. The range of "Wunschliste" is supposed to be between 8-18 for each of the values of "terital". First 4 then 7 and so on.

```
while not BuBu:

try:


    Wunschliste = range(8-18)
    tertial = '4,7,10'

    Wunsch1 = Wu1 = browser.find_element_by_xpath(f"/html/body/div[7]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr{Wunschliste}]/td[{tertial}]/img")
    Wu1.click()
    print("Wunsch1 eingeloggt")
    browser.find_element_by_class_name("pj_nicht_buchbar")
    print("nope")

    time.sleep(3)
```

except: ...

Thanks! Hope it makes sense

Comment: This is not supported in f-strings. Write a loop.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This part is part of an try and except loop already. Do I have to write each block for each pair up then?

Comment: `try` and `except` has nothing to do with a loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can write nested for-loops to handle each case:

```
for Wunschliste in range(8,19):
    for tertial in [4,7,10]:
        Wunsch1 = Wu1 = browser.find_element_by_xpath(f"/html/body/div[7]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr{Wunschliste}]/td[{tertial}]/img")
        Wu1.click()
```

The range is from 8 to 19 because then last handled number would be 18.

Answer (score 0):

[range()](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_range.asp) function returns the sequence of the given number between the given range.

Moreover, *`tertial`* seems to be a list of *`integers`*.

So while passing them within the xpath you have to convert them into string characters and you can use the following solution:

```
for Wunschliste in range(8,19):
    for tertial in [4,7,10]:
        Wu1 = browser.find_element_by_xpath(f"/html/body/div[7]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr{str(Wunschliste)}]/td[{str(tertial)}]/img")
        Wu1.click()
        print("Wunsch1 eingeloggt")
```